Dependency between Flutter and Kotlin
I'm quite new in programming with flutter and dart. Using the location package, I got messages like the following one:
FlutterLocationService.kt: (282, 25): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
I startet to isolate the issue. So I updated my AndroidStudio Toolchain and my Flutter environment. After that, I've created a new project with flutter create test. This Project works on android as expected. As soon as I added the package location in version 5.0.3, I got the error messages again.
I'm confused about interaction of Flutter and Kotlin. Why does Flutter use Kotlin at all? How can I update Kotlin and Gradle in general?
I found multiple posts for upgrading Gradle for an existing project. But I don't understand why this is needed for a new Project? In my opinion Flutter expects an integrated Gradle/Kotlin Version which it is tested for. So an update shouldn't be needed. But if so, I'm surprised that I have nowhere seen a Note on the Flutter Packages Page that the location package uses a manual update for Gradle/Kotlin.
Thanks for trying to explain this issue to a newbie.
Regards Markus
